# How to get value from lightning-progress-ring and pass it on to js variable in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have below lwc code working. I need to change the "variant" of the lightning-progress-ring based on the value percent. I'm facing challenge to pass the value={record.Percentage__c} to Javascript to perform comparison of value. Please help to get the value on to js.

```
<template for:each={records} for:item="record">
<span key={record.Id} class="circularProgress">
<lightning-progress-ring class="slds-progress-ring__progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" value={record.Percentage__c} variant={variant}>
</lightning-progress-ring>
</span>
</template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Expressions don't have parameters. You need to transform your `records` variable so it holds the data you want. For example, you could write:

```
<template for:each={wrappers} for:item="wrapper">
<span key={wrapper.record.Id} class="circularProgress">
<lightning-progress-ring 
    class="slds-progress-ring__progress" 
    role="progressbar" 
    aria-valuemin="0" 
    aria-valuemax="100" 
    value={wrapper.record.Percentage__c} 
    variant={wrapper.variant}>
</lightning-progress-ring>
</span>
</template>
```

Which you'd want to change your JavaScript to match:

```
const calcVariant = (record) => {
  switch(true) {
    case record.Percentage__c < 20: return 'variant-a';
    case record.Percentage__c < 40: return 'variant-b';
    default: return 'variant-c';
  }
}
this.wrappers = this.records.map(
  (record)=>({ variant: calcVariant(record), record })
);
```

This is just an example, you can write whatever logic you want into the function to determine the variant. The main takeaways here are that you (a) need to calculate your desired values in JavaScript, and (b) need to include that data into the Array's objects that you're iterating over.